# guardar datos en un objecto Utilizando FOR

Tags: javascript, object, bucle-for

tengo este for, la idea es ir guardando los datos en el objecto:

```
 let data_array = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //console.log("datos completos ->  " +  data[i].id_expediente);
          data_array = {
                    'id_expediente':data[i].id_expediente,
                    'demandado':data[i].demandado,
                    'direccion':data[i].direccion,
                    'status':"",
                    'fecha_asignada':data[i].fecha_asig,
                    'tipo_juicio':data[i].tipo_juicio,
                    'lat':"",
                    'lng':""
                };

        }
```

y al imprimir con

```
console.log("data->" + JSON.stringify(data_array));
```

solo me guarda el ultimo dato.

```
{
"id_expediente": "3",
"demandado": "JORGE AVILA BERRIO",
"direccion": "Barlovento 1",
"status": "",
"fecha_asignada": "2018-05-01 00:00:00",
"tipo_juicio": "1",
"lng": ""
}
```

Que es lo que tengo mal dentro del For ?, la intencion es generar este formato con los datos del For

```
{
"expedientes": [
{
  "id_expediente": "1",
  "demandado": "JORGE AVILA BERRIO",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1",
  "status": "",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-05-01 00:00:00",
  "tipo_juicio": "1",
  "lng": ""
},
{
  "id_expediente": "2",
  "demandado": "JORGE AVILA BERRIO",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1",
  "status": "",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018",
  "tipo_juicio": "1",
  "lng": ""
},
{
  "id_expediente": "3",
  "demandado": "JORGE AVILA BERRIO",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1",
  "status": "",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018",
  "tipo_juicio": "1",
  "lng": ""
}
]
}
```

Comment: prueba agregando [] antes de asignar los datos así:    data_array[] = {
                    'id_expediente':data[i].id_expediente,
                    'demandado':data[i].demandado,
                    'direccion':data[i].direccion,
                    'status':"",
                    'fecha_asignada':data[i].fecha_asig,
                    'tipo_juicio':data[i].tipo_juicio,
                    'lat':"",
                    'lng':""
                };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe a que constantemente estas sobreescribiendo **data_array** .

Lo ideal es que lo hagas de la siguiente manera:

```
data_array.push(data[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambiando el let por un var, y haciendo push de los items al array.

```
  var data_array = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //console.log("datos completos ->  " +  data[i].id_expediente);
          data_array.push({
                    'id_expediente':data[i].id_expediente,
                    'demandado':data[i].demandado,
                    'direccion':data[i].direccion,
                    'status':"",
                    'fecha_asignada':data[i].fecha_asig,
                    'tipo_juicio':data[i].tipo_juicio,
                    'lat':"",
                    'lng':""
                });
        }
```